# HHVM cms, user permission on creating files

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I am creating cms, and i am using hhvm as php compiler.

hhvm is running as user nginx, and every file or folder that creates as user nginx:nginx.

Then that user cant delete or change file via ftp.

How can i solve this?

I want to my files or folders created by php script have user - user:nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions.

1. Add user into nginx group and grant writing permission to group members ( `chmod -R 775 HHVM_WEB_DIRECTORY` ).
2. Use `setfacl` command, such as `setfacl -Rm u:user:rwx HHVM_WEB_DIRECTORY && setfacl -dm u:user:rwx HHVM_WEB_DIRECTORY`